# Move a div with jQuery in a non-destructive manner?

Tags: jquery

Okay, so I have 3 divs...

```
<div id="video"></div>
<div id="info"></div>
<div id="chat"></div>
```

I am using jQuery to move the divs around on a button press.

```
$('#chat').insertBefore('#video');
```

There is just an issue I have with this. I believe what this function does is duplicate/clone the `chat` div, insert it before the `video` div, then destroy the original `chat` div. However, this doesn't work well, because as its obvious, the `chat` div contains a chatroom.

So the way its cloning and destroys loads up a new chat element, which not only takes up a lot of resources, but also forces the user to log back into the chatroom since its a different instance.

Is there a way to move a div in a non-destructive manner? Without cloning and destroying? Some sort of way to physically move the div?

Comment: How does the `#chat` HTML element "contain" an instance of a chat room?

Comment: I don't see it functioning that way. Also jQuery document for `insertBefore` does not mention destroying the original element.

Comment: You can see an example of how this works here: http://8wayrun.com/streams/8wayrun247.2/channel

Click the "side-by-side" button to see the insertBefore.

Comment: @JasonAxelrod Pardon my understanding but in the link you provided, it seems to work fine.

Comment: @JayPatel clicking on the `SbS` button you'll see the chat actually reload it's contents which might lead to the loss of the chat contents. Actually I would target that issue to the chat app, not the way jQ performs with Inserts.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan You're right. It does reload the chat window.

Comment: @JayPatel Looks like iframe contents are reloaded? :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I don't see `iframe`. It might have something to do with `animate` function. At the end of animation `insertBefore` is called.

Comment: @JayPatel take a closer look: `#embedChat` = IFRAME

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Sorry. I was using search function of Firebug. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @JayPatel updated my live demo with that chat app

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33668/discussion-between-jay-patel-and-roko-c-buljan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I'm afraid it's not possible to move an IFRAME from one place in the DOM to another place without reloading it's contents.**

`insertBefore` has an issue with dynamic content, specially if you're about to handle 
**IFRAMES**

**[LIVE DEMO with chat](http://jsbin.com/aximab/5/edit)**

if you click the SWAP that will `insertBefore()` the iframe element 
 you'll notice that the iframe content gets **refreshed**
**the same happens with your chat app (module)**

Answer (score 1):

You can try the native `insertBefore`:

```
var video = document.getElementById('video'),
    chat  = document.getElementById('chat');

video.parentNode.insertBefore(chat, video);
```

In a perfect world, the jQuery method should work this way. But if you f.ex have multiple targets and jQuery is being "nice", maybe this way of doing it will shed some light onto your situation...

Answer (score 0):

[Document](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) from jQuery site on `insertBefore` states the following.

> If an element selected this way is **inserted into a single location**
>   elsewhere in the DOM, **it will be moved before the target (not cloned)**
>   and a new set consisting of the inserted element is returned.

Above statement applies to your situation. **So your `div` is not destroyed or cloned.**

> If **there is more than one target element**, however, **cloned copies
>   of the inserted element will be created for each target after the
>   first, and that new set (the original element plus clones) is
>   returned**.

In case if it the element is inserted before many targets, it will be cloned.

Comment: That would assume that there is more than one `#video` target, and that would be invalid HTML.

Comment: @David What in the case of `$('#chat').insertBefore('div')`

Comment: yes, in that case this rule will apply. I’m just making things clear.

Comment: Yeah I agree that In the OP's case the second argument of multiple targets do not apply.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue a different way. Since people confirmed that its not possible to move an iFRAME from one place in the DOM to another without reloading it's contents...

Instead of moving the div in the DOM, I simply left it where it was and applied "position: absolute" to the div I wanted on the top, forcing it to the top.